# Javascript check if any of the words in string starts with

Tags: javascript, regex

I am creating javascript function to filter ul list li based on input

```
textli.match("^he")
```

Above code matches all the words starting with ab.But I also want to check other words seperated by space.

```
hello world
```

so to match above string textli.match("^he") will do the job , but what if I also want to filter **world** with textli.match("^wo")

Comment: how _ab_ matches _he_ ?

Comment: Replace `^` with `\b`. `/\bwo/` to find the word starting with `wo`.

Comment: `ab[^ \n]*` would do the job + global flag

Comment: do you want to get the first 2 characters of all words? or only he and wo ?

Comment: its inputbox to filter list , so it must work for any number of characters